# Error while installing Facebook.Client library

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, sdk, nuget

I'm developing a windows 8 facebook built in app in visual studio 2013.
I need to insert a login button to my app in order to use facebook features... I use Facebook SDK for .NET and trying to install the Facebook.Client Package using NuGet console (`Install-Package Facebook.Client -pre`) but I get an annoying error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Facebook.Client
>   0.8.5-alpha'. You are trying to install this package into a project that tar gets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with tha t framework. For more information, contact the package
>   author. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Facebook.Client -pre
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I tried change my framework to 4.0 (from 4.5) but still the same error....
must say that I just updated NuGet to its latest version.